# Tornado based python game server latency problem on amazon cloud

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, tornado, latency

I have tornado based game server hosted on amazon cloud 1gb ram and 10gn harddisk.I have 500 users per day and cocurrent users are 30+ at agiven time . users are based around the world and I am hosting cloud machine in USA west as most of users are from USA .
I am facing Network latency issue . When i have single user reponse time is 1 second which is also high but as users move to 10+ this reponse time starts dropping to 2 seconds .for for 50+ users its 8 Seconds .
I did test and wrote test script .
test1 .

1. tested with same test script as mentioned above , itested on my local machine master code running on local and testscript also on local latency less than 1000ms (90% median 220ms)
2. run the same code on cloud , test script on same cloud same result
3. running game server  on cloud and script on local latency 8 seconds

Answer (score 0):

**1. Network I/O**

If you're doing network-bound operations in your request handlers (such as connecting to a database, or sending requests to another API), then use the `await` statements for those tasks so that Python can pause the coroutine and process other requests asynchronously.

**2. CPU tasks and Disk I/O**

If you're doing cpu-bound operations (any code other than network I/O that takes over a few milliseconds to run), then use [`IOLoop.run_in_executor`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor) to run those tasks in a separate thread. This will free up the main thread so that the CPU can run other tasks.

Tornado is a single-threaded server. That means the CPU can run only one thing at a given time. So, if a single response takes 220ms of CPU time, and if you have 10 connected clients, it would take over 2 seconds to serve the 10th client. And this time just increases *(though not always proportionally, as Python may reuse CPU cache) as the number of clients goes up.

It appears the CPU on the cloud server is not as fast as your personal CPU, hence the increased latency.